# Margin-top/Padding-top having no effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a jQuery form-field validator, and at the moment I'm working on building in the pop-up notifications in CSS.

The problem is, I can't get `.notification-point` to align to the center of `.notification-body`, regardless of the application of `margin-top/padding-top` properties.

Here's a link to my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Jtd/8/

Any help/edits would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/Z6Jtd/9/

There you go.

*Note: I changed your javascript a little. I removed .fadeOut; I would highly recommend creating a function for `.focusout()` - or better yet, detect changes to the value and when it matches the required rule, hide the message.*

---

For future readers:

The solution to this issue was to wrap both the *marker* ("point") and the *body* ("message") in a container with `position: relative;` on it.

Then, I positioned the marker using `position: absolute;` and `top: 8px`.

Next, I added  `margin-left: 12px` to the *message* in order to not overlap the marker.

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 13px Arial;
    color: #555;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border: 0;
}

.notify-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

.notify-point {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) transparent transparent;
    border-width: 6px;
}

.notify-body {
    margin-left: 12px; /* push the body out to make room for point */
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font: bold 11px Arial, Helvetica;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

*note: above code is modified to not take up loads of room with `border-radius`, etc*

**HTML**

```
<div id="email">
<input name="1" type="text" value="Enter your email address"/>
    <div class="notify-wrap x1">
        <div class="notify-point"></div>
        <div class="notify-body">
            You've entered an invalid email address.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*note: on **notify-wrap**, i added the class `x1` to define a specific error message to keep in line with the OP's original formatting for javascript.*

**Javascript** (jQuery)

```
$('input').focus( function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('name');
    $('div.notify-wrap.x' + num).css('display','inline-block');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't even realize there was an event handler called `.focusout()`, thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. The *best* way to handle error/warning messages is to show it once the problem occurs, and keep it shown until the problem is fixed. Using `.focus()` and `.focusout()` are great, but just as a UX suggestion I'd use them for something more along the lines of a helpful hint or tip, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/Z6Jtd/10/. Then, with your validation, add an `.error` class to the input and style it with a red border/etc. Just some suggestions - glad I could help with your original issue!

Comment: Yeah, the fiddle wasn't a realistic version of what I was planning to do, more a mock-up to test out usage of those notification type things. It's CSS3 dependent anyway, so I'm going to move it to a single `.class` using multiple background-images. :)

Comment: Yeah, that or just put the marker in a sprite and then use `background: url('path_to_opaque_bg_for_ie');`, followed by `backgorund: rgba(0,0,0,.8);` for 100% compliance without forcing a bg image load on browsers that support rgba.